# python divide the data into intervals

Tags: python, dataframe, probability

I need to transform the data into an interval variation series

```
import numpy as np
import math
import sys
import os
import pandas as pd
```

```
data = pd.read_csv("euro-dollar-exchange-rate-historical-chart.csv",index_col=['date'] )
data
```

```
df=data['2017-01-02':]
df
```

```
    value;
date    
1999-01-04  1.1825;
1999-01-05  1.1774;
1999-01-06  1.1622;
1999-01-07  1.1706;
1999-01-08  1.1577;
    ...         ...
2022-11-01  0.9875;
2022-11-02  0.9815;
2022-11-03  0.9752;
2022-11-04  0.9984;
2022-11-05  0.9984;
```

6346 rows × 1 columns

```
l=int(input())
df1=pd.cut(df,bins=l)
df1
```

> ValueError: Input array must be 1 dimensional

Answer (score 1):

Do you want intervals on exchange-rate or the dates? I think you're trying to pd.cut a Series-object, try to use pd.cut(df.values, bins=l) if you want the exchange-rate, or pd.cut(df.index, bins = l) if you want date-intervals.

Comment: df1=pd.cut(df.values,bins=l) >ValueError: Input array must be 1 dimensional

Comment: My bad. Try df.value or np.array(df.value), without the *s* in the end. I'm assuming the exchange-rate column is named "value" here?

Comment: @pyrifo is right, the issue is that you are passing an entire dataframe, while pd.cut() expects an array.

Comment: df1=pd.cut(df[df.columns[0]],bins=l)>can only concatenate str (not "float") to str

Comment: df1=pd.cut(df.value,bins=l)>AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'value'  But df.columns >Index([' value'], dtype='object')